# How make web api return json in needed format?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I'm using following code in web api to return json:

So, here is dto class. But it's not clear how to map it to result.

```
public class grafikresult
{
    int kodg { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
    DateTime data { get; set; }
    byte pax { get; set; }
    byte ch { get; set; }
}
```

Here is controller code:

```
// GET api/Grafik/5
    public IHttpActionResult GetGrafik(int id)
    {
        PhuketEntities db = new PhuketEntities();
        xTourist t = db.xTourist.Find(id);
        var result = from a in db.Grafik
                     join b in db.Exc on a.Excursion equals b.Kod
                     join c in db.Dates on a.Kodd equals c.kodd
                     join d in db.Staff on a.Guide equals d.Kod
                     where c.Date > t.ArrDate && c.Дата < t.DepDate
                     select new { kodg = a.Kodg, name = d.Name, data = c.Date, pax = t.Pax, ch = t.Child };
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

This returns new json like that:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "$values": [{
        "$id": "2",
        "kodg": -1643387437,
        "name": null,
        "data": "2014-02-07T00:00:00",
        "pax": 2,
        "ch": 0
    }, {...}]
}
```

How should I change web api controller code to be able get this json:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "kodg": -1643387437,
    "name": null,
    "data": "2014-02-07T00:00:00",
    "pax": 2,
    "ch": 0
    }, {...}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

### 1. Create classes for your Json

Before you use that you WILL need to convert your JSON object to C# classes. Try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-C) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260631/convert-json-into-class-object-in-c-sharp).

In case you are having trouble defining classes, here is what I think should work for you.

Class for first json.

```
public class JsonClassA
{
    int id{ get; set; }
    Details values { get; set; }
}  

public class Details
{
    int kodg { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
    DateTime data { get; set; }
    byte pax { get; set; }
    byte ch { get; set; }
}
```

Class for second json.

```
public class JSONClassB
{
    int kodg { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
    DateTime data { get; set; }
    byte pax { get; set; }
    byte ch { get; set; }
}
```

### 2. Deserialize using JavaScriptSerialize:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
JsonClassA jsonClassA = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonClassA>(jsonInput)
```

### 3. Map using Automapper

Say your first Json represent class `JsonClassA` and your second JSON represents class `JSONClassB`.

Using Automapper this could easily be done as follows and be returned from your controller.

```
JSONClassB finalOutput = AutoMapper.CreateMap<JsonClassA, JSONClassB>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.prop1, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.propAAA))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.prop2, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.propBBB));
return Ok(finalOutput );
```

Comment: this looks great. Let me try this solution.

Comment: your solution, is it similar to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657122/how-to-format-json-return-value-in-nice-html-with-asp-net-web-api?rq=1

Comment: @andrey.shedko No, i saw the link you posted its a completely different question and answer. Did this solution work for you ?

Comment: Did not try yet. I will let you know.

Comment: jsonInput should be result of the LINQ query (var result), right?

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot for your assistance, but I ask wrong question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a DTO class having the exact structure you need to return. Then you would map the structure of the items on `result` to `PhuketDTO` and assign the DTO list to `Ok` as you currently do for `result`.

Comment: Claudio, my background based on vb.net and linq, so I will be appreciate a lot if you can show any example of that.

Comment: @andrey.shedko: check the structure of the json you need to return an translate that to a C# class structure. If you have troubles with that come again and I'll be glad to help.

Comment: To say honestly, yes, I have troubles with that.